# Matrix singularity catch-22 in regression analysis

Tags: regression, variance-inflation-factor

I'm trying to run a multiple regression, but I'm getting a singular matrix exception. I assume this means that there is high collinearity among my independent variables, so for each X I produce its own regression with it as the dependent variable, and the other X'es as the independent variables. I do this to calculate its VIF, so that I can determine which X'es to drop from the global regression. However, some of these X regressions ALSO produce singular matrix exceptions. How do I work-around this catch-22? I need to run regressions to calculate the VIFs, but I can't run regressions because the variables are collinear?

Comment: I know an algorithm for this, but it is somewhat involved. Have you already created a correlation matrix to test for perfect correlation between pairs of variables? If so, did you be sure to drop one variable whenever you dummied out your categorical variables?

Comment: I do drop one variable when dummying out my categorical variables. Also, I initially was doing the correlation matrix you mention and dropping variables with pairwise correlation > 0.8. The problem is that in my case, I have a dataset where doing this is not enough, I still get matrix singularity -- presumably because of "complex" multicollinearities involving more than 2 variables being correlated with each other. This is why I tried to move on to VIF analysis, rather than just pairwise correlation testing.

Comment: And, just to be clear, do you have more observations than variables?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm thinking of using LASSO regression to solve this problem rather than trying to weed out multicollinearities.

Comment: I don't know if you will see this, but stats packages (R, SAS, and doubtless others) will do this for you from your regression. Also, I think condition indexes are a better method than VIF.